# How this program has time complexity Big Oh (n^2logn)?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

```
  int unknown(int n)
    {
    int i,j,k=0;
    for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=2;j<=n;j=j+2)
        k=k+n/2;
    return k;
    }
```

Is the complexity mentioned by me is right ?If yes, how ? Please explain in detail.

Comment: How about instead explaining why you think that's right, then asking if there are any errors in your reasoning? That would make a better question.

Comment: what @paisanco said, but also (less importantly) format your code properly to make it easier to read

Comment: @paisanco The reason I presented my question in this way is because I have been assured that the answer is correct. I am not convinced though but its correct by the terms of few reference books. I am not in flow with asymptotic analysis thats why put it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outer loop executes n / 2 times

Inner loop executes (n - 2) / 2 times.

(Ignoring truncation effects with integer division)

So complexity is O(n^2). (Assuming O(1) for all arithmetic operations)